# C++ : struct vs function for ordering elements

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, priority-queue

I have a `struct` with two fields :

```
struct road {
    int from, len ;
};
```

For some reason, I need to be able to order my `road`s :

- by ascending `from` in an array
- by ascending `len` in a priority queue

I have thus included :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
```

I have come across websites suggesting to overload the `operator<`, but because of the two possible orderings that just feels wrong and it would only solve one of the two.

By messing around with textbooks, I got this to work :

```
bool cmpFrom (const road & a, const road & b) {
    return (a.from < b.from) ;
}

struct cmpLen {
    bool operator () (const road & a, const road & b){
        return (a.len < b.len) ;
    }
};
```

To be used with :

```
std::sort(trips, trips + nbRoads, &cmpFrom) ;
std::priority_queue<road, std::vector<road>, cmpLen> pickRoad ;
```

Where `trips` is of course a `road []`.

It compiles perfectly (haven't tried running it, but it should be fine), but it seems weird to define two very similar comparators in two quite different manners, so isn't there a way to define both comparison methods the same way ?

Changing the definition of `cmpFrom` to

```
struct cmpFrom {
    bool operator () (const road & a, const road & b){
        return (a.from < b.from) ;
    }
};
```

Gives

```
chantier.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
chantier.cpp:38:48: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     std::sort(trips, trips + nbRoads, &cmpFrom) ;
```

Which I assume means "You gave me a type when I was expecting a reference".

While writing

```
bool cmpLen (const road & a, const road & b) {
    return (a.len <= b.len) ;
}
```

Gives

```
chantier.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
chantier.cpp:52:56: error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Sequence, class _Compare> class std::priority_queue’
     std::priority_queue<road, std::vector<road>, cmpLen> pickRoad ;
                                                        ^
chantier.cpp:52:56: note:   expected a type, got ‘cmpLen’
chantier.cpp:56:30: error: request for member ‘top’ in ‘pickRoad’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
...
```

Is there a way to make one of these comparison methods work for both containers ? Or is there perhaps a third way of doing this that could work with both ?

What if I had needed to use the same ordering with both containers ? Would that have required defining twice the same comparison method, but with one inside a `struct` ?

Comment: what is the question? Aaa... you have edited question to express which answer you are approving. Please do not do it like this. Just mark tick next to answer which was helpful for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost have it.  In `std::sort` you need an object that you can call `operator()` on.  Using

```
bool cmpFrom (const road & a, const road & b) {
    return (a.from < b.from) ;
}
std::sort(trips, trips + nbRoads, &cmpFrom);
```

works because a function pointer can be used like a function.  When you change `cmpFrom` to

```
struct cmpFrom {
    bool operator () (const road & a, const road & b){
        return (a.from < b.from) ;
    }
};
```

you can't use `std::sort(trips, trips + nbRoads, &cmpFrom);` anymore because you can't apply `&` to a type name.  Instead what you need to do is get an object of `cmpFrom` and you do that like

```
std::sort(trips, trips + nbRoads, cmpFrom{});
```

now both the `priority_queue` and `sort` could use `cmpFrom`.

Answer (score 5):

It's easier to define both as structures, because you can always create an object from a type and it will behave as expected, but getting a type from a function and having it act as a caller for the function is much more difficult.

You were in fact almost there with `struct cmpFrom`. However, you've correctly noted that `std::sort` expects a comparator *object* (such as a function), not a type. Of course, doing `&cmpFrom` where `cmpFrom` is a type is not valid C++. Instead, you need to create an object of that type; thanks to the `operator()` defined, the object will be callable and do what you want. So just call `std::sort` like this:

```
std::sort(trips, trips + nbRoads, cmpFrom{});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `std::sort` function and `std::priority_queue` class template want two different things: `sort` wants a *callable object*, while `priority_queue` template wants a type, which allows creating objects.

Because of that, `sort` is more omnivorous than `priority_queue` - you can use it with either functions or functors. The only thing you need is to provide it with a real object (while currently in your code you are trying to take an address of a type, which makes no sense).

To fix it in your example just change the code to

```
std::sort(trips, trips + nbRoads, cmpFrom{});
```